# User defined schemas in data warehouse

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, oltp, snowflake-schema

I have about 7-8 user-defined schemas (Reference, Finance, Admin, ORG, etc) in my OLTP database. I do have ODS db which is almost a replica on OLTP.
 I want to build a data warehouse for this. How many schemas are recommended while building a warehouse? am I supposed to create all the required tables in just 2-3 schemas if going by snowflake approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way you structure you warehouse is entirely up to you. You can create as many or as little schemas as you like in order to fit your needs.

Normally you'd only have a few schemas, probably soemthing like:

- Staging
- Config
- Presentation

This question is quite broad however and it seems like you need to do a bit of research and design work first on how to build a warehouse. Regardless this isn't really a Snowflake question but rather a data warehousing one which is almost opinion based.